# VS Code Terminal Not Allowing Typing

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS code terminal was working fine, until one day when I tried to work on a project, that was still open in VS code, my terminal didn't allow me to type any commands. I couldn't type anything. This is the screen that I get.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, for those of you struggling with the same problem, I've managed to solve it by clicking on the drop-down menu that says `powershell` and changing it to `cmd`.

Comment: There is no cmd option

Comment: If you are in Linux, there won't be a cmd option, as the command prompt is only available in windows.

Comment: It solved. I always hate powershell

Answer (score 8):

this happened to me and simply

1. close vs code
2. right click on it
3. run as administrator
4. open the terminal and it will work

this problem happened when I changed the default path of CMD

Comment: Perfect, this fixed my issue in 2021!

Comment: This fixed my issue, after I updated VSCode to version 1.64.2.

Comment: Always was good, I didn't want to update VSCode, but get the issue like this. Then I read the comment of @Boat. And decided to update to 1.77.0 (1 wk ago). And it's worked. Thanks. Didn't understand what's happened.

Comment: For me (Windows user), I just closed vs code and reopened. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when running **ionic serve** command which runs the development server on the localhost. I paid attention after executing the command above, and it said:

**Use Ctrl+C to quit this process**

Pressing Ctrl+C then displays:

**Terminate batch job (Y/N)?**

Type Y or y

then the command prompt is shown again!

Here is a sample terminal window - trimmed for brevity:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, I tried using Powershell/CMD/Bash and I was having errors/blank terminal. I found typing `echo hello` and pressing `CTRL + C` made it appear. So in fact, everything was working, my terminal was just blank/glitched out, but was really accepting input.

Answer (score 1):

For who has this problem using React. This happens when you start a live version using npm start. The terminal that handles the live version of the app cannot be used for anything else.
So to continue using the terminal you need to open a new terminal to use in parallel. To do so just click on the plus icon in the top right corner of the terminal panel then choose the "Power Shell" option. This will open a new terminal without restarting visual studio.

Comment: Thank you, just started with react and it was driving insane that I needed to re-open vscode in order to write in the terminal after npm start.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac, when working with Python, this helped me: instead of clicking on the "Run Code" option, click on "Run Python file", in the right corner.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users this is solved by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58647330/2190800):

File -> Preferences -> Setting -> Features -> Terminal -> Inherit Env

Answer (score 0):

I found two vscode on my desktop, I opened the other one and it worked. Looks like I updated it but the older one didn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> can help to get out of this frozen state, that will be easier to do with VSCode 1.64 (Jan. 2022)

The terminal can type the answer for you.

> ### [Terminal -- Auto-reply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/8687aa0fb005f35849cc5e5fdee393c76fe69fb1/release-notes/v1_64.md#terminal)
>
> The terminal is now able to automatically reply when a specific sequences of characters is received.
>
> A good example of where this is useful, which is also the only default case, is the Windows batch script message `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when running a batch script.
> This typically just ends up causing problems for the user.
>
> The terminal will now automatically reply with `Y` and enter (`\r`) which makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Windows feel much better.
>
> Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will immediately reply to the question and return to the prompt:
>
> [image]
>
> Theme: [Sapphire](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.theme-sapphire)
>
> The feature was made generically so you can setup custom replies for other thing, just be careful when doing this as you are sending text to the process automatically.
>
> For example you could use it to automatically update Oh My Zsh when prompted:
>
> ```json
> "terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
>  "[Oh My Zsh] Would you like to check for updates? [Y/n]": "Y\r"
> }
> ```
>
> If you use Clink and enable their similar feature, you can disable it in Clink or in VS Code by setting the reply to null to avoid the two features conflicting with each other:
>
> ```json
> "terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
>  "Terminate batch job (Y/N)": null
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Go to terminal, preferences, settings. 
Check "run code in terminal"
Restart VS.

Answer (score -1):

I changed from bash to powershell in terminal first but the command prompt still not shown.
Then I navigate to File -> Perferences -> Settings and it starts working (command prompt shown)

Comment: How did just 'navigating' fix your problem??

Answer (score -1):

This seems to just be a display problem. It happened to me when I changed my display settings for desktop icon and app scaling settings.

I managed to fix the problem by simply restarting my computer and re-opening VS code

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem ... In my case just run vs-code as administrator and works

Answer (score -1):

It will be working by pressing the "q" key on your keyboard.