# Visual Studio Code - Terminal Blank Screen

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I've been using Visual Studio Code since it was in beta and one of the features I like best about it is the integrated terminal for using the Angular CLI in app. I've had it working fine since I had the laptop, but I re-installed Windows 10 over the Xmas break and obviously as a result had to re-install Visual Studio Code.

Since then I've had issues with the Terminal, it's blank until you hit return, at which point you see the path, but not the usual copyright notice you should get from the Windows Command Line.

Before hitting return:
[image: VS code Terminal 1]

After hitting return:
[image: VS Code Terminal 2]

And this is what I was expecting directly from the Windows 10 Command Line:
[image: Windows Terminal]

So far I've tried the following:

- The usual Windows shut down / restart
- Re-installing VS Code (even changed from regular to insiders)
- Changing the default Command Line Shell from CMD to Powershell and
  back again
- Adding a new Command Line Shell

Is there anything else I can try? Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Comment: Recently I have had the same issue but I can just click and type and that seems to fix it for that session.

Comment: I can just click and type if I want to but the issue is that I teach online and when I'm recording I don't want my install to look broken so I'd prefer to have it fixed

Comment: I searched for a GitHub issue on this a couple of weeks back and found nothing at the time.

Comment: If you see below I've found the answer :) - a recent search of Issues on Github led to a duplicate issue that was fixed today. See below for more details.

Comment: Thanks.   [and 7 more characters here to be at least 15.]

Comment: I thought this happened to me only after trying to customize (reduce) the font size in the VSC terminals, but reverting to the default font size doesn't seem to fix things. Probably a coincidence, with what Web Develop Wolf reported below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097196/999556) being the most likely actual culprit.

Comment: 2023 and I just started experiencing this with a cygwin terminal (it's been working fine for years). I have a feeling a blank terminal is a symptom of many possible bugs.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76542

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research I've found that this is a bug in VS Code with the application they use to integrate the shell. Looks like Android Studio has the same issue too. You can read about the more specific how / when / what etc. here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57803

This has been fixed on the insiders release that landed for me today (08/01/2019), not sure when this will be rolled out to the general release (if not January then I would imagine it might roll out in February barring no further issues).

So for anyone else still getting this issue, update to the latest version of VS Code. If you have done and you're still getting the same problem you can check and report issues here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

[image: Fixed Terminal Window]

Comment: Its March 13th, still having this issue... (version 1.32.1)

Comment: The latest version is 1.33.0 and the issue is still there.

Comment: and again in 1.33.1

Comment: If you read the Github issue the fix is in Windows console, to be released in Windows 1903. If you have Windows preview build 18309 it should have the fix.

Comment: still have this June 6, 2019

Comment: still have this issue july 18

Comment: ++ July 29th. Windows on latest, VS Code on latest. It's unfortunate all the github issues on this keep getting closed, pointing fingers at other closed issues.

Comment: ++ Same issue with the current release on September 4th.

Comment: Same here, unfortunately.

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: Still not fixed on Windows June 19, 2020

Comment: I still have this issue :( 2021-02-21

Answer (score 110):

My solution for VSCode 1.39.2 with Ubuntu has been:

File -> Preferences -> Setting -> Features -> Terminal -> Inherit Env

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I would love to know why.

Comment: Was checked by default for me on 19.10 and does not work.

Comment: Worked for me (ubuntu)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, VSCode 1.40.2. The Terminal session is under the Workspace tab now

Comment: I had to remove the line  
`"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,`
from my user settings (select Edit in settings.json from the Settings/User tab view)

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu with a `conda` environment.

Comment: Not working for me on Ubuntu 20.04 / 1.52.1 / zsh

Comment: You are the best... Save me un ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Worked on Arch, but the font looks funny

Comment: Turning this option off worked for me on Windows 10

Comment: Solved it for me for miniconda on Zorin OS. See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_launch-terminals-with-clean-environments

Comment: If your vs code terminal shows black screen after sleeping for some times, try this ```"terminal.integrated.experimentalRefreshOnResume": true```
or refer to this https://bleepcoder.com/vscode/416235055/terminal-shows-corrupt-texture-sometimes-when-resuming-the

Answer (score 34):

I have the same problem with PowerShell even after installing the 1.32.1 update. I fixed it by going to PowerShell options and checked the "Use legacy console" option and now it works as it should and I thinks it should work with cmd too.

Comment: I can't seem to find this setting in VS Code 1.34.0 :( Maybe it was renamed to something else? Or is the "Use legacy console" option you mentioned not in VS Code, but in some other global PowerShell settings somewhere?

Comment: @deadlydog yes , it is in the global PowerShell properties

Comment: also worked for me... I also set the console buffer width to 80.

Comment: Worked for me. This should be the accepted answer and noted as a work around.

Comment: for those who aren't familiar with powershell,
open powershell --> right click title bar --> properties --> Use legacy console

Comment: That  works for me too only after setting "Use legacy console" in PowerShell (windows 10 x64 pro). Thanks

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem in visual studio code 1.41.1 in ubuntu 18.04,I solved it by editing the settings.json by going through  settings and search for 'Inherit Env'and opening Edit in settings.json and changing

```
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true
```

The screenshot is provided below

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, tried bunch of different stuff and finally this one worked.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the fix:

1. CLick bottom left setting wheel
2. go to setting > Features > terminal
3. Select Explorer kind: Intergrated
4. Change inheritEnv to true.
   [image]

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem with PowerShell, Gitbash,  etc. with code version 1.36.0. 
See Version info
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4dcm.png)

I could clear the problem with the following steps:

- Open PowerShell in admin Mode. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5bmp.png)
- At the bottom of the item Legacy console is a checkbox, which is selected by default.
- Deselect this option then Save. 
  [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTadF.png)
- Reboot Code Finally, the console appears as expected.
  [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex61Y.png)

Comment: Top left Menu -> Properties -> Options. Use the bin icon on the current terminals in VS Code

Comment: It is baffling that 1.5 years later I have to use this workaround to get the terminal in Code to work as it should by default. What are the devs doing?

Answer (score 8):

Inside the terminal window,  Press `Ctrl + c` and hit `enter`

Though it's not a permanent solution but its a quick fix to get the juice flowing while you are working with VSCode

Answer (score 8):

Remove the following line in `settings.json` file

```
terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
```

You can locate settings.json file in the following locations —

- **Windows** `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- **macOS** `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- **Linux** `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Answer (score 8):

This works for me. Tested in windows 10

Right click and open the properties of visual studio code short cut.

1. Add  --disable-gpu to the end of Target.
2. And in the compatibility tab, uncheck  compatibility Mode and click OK.

Then Rerun the visual studio code application. It should work.

[image]

Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2835_ZJGCQA

Comment: Works in Windows 8 as well

Comment: It worked for me on windows 10 Thank You!

Comment: I did something similiar. I went to Nvidia Panel Control > 3dSettings > Added VScode > Disabled Anti Alising. Worked perfectly. Before all the VsCode looked blurry too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while working on CMD in my VSCode. I fixed it by going to the Terminal Menu in the VS Code and selected New Terminal. And a new cmd terminal opened up and it working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code prompted a dialog at bottom right corner recommending me to switch the `RenderType` option to `dom`, because it felt it was running slow. Then the blank-terminal issued was gone.
My environment was a vm of Ubuntu 16.04 running on win10.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix for Code in Ubuntu-18.04 :
The issue doesn't appear when opened through the terminal.
Go to the settings in the bottom left and search for "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv".
Check the box for this in user section that way terminal will inherit user's environment. 
Done!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, try format your answers so they're as readable as possible. Stackoverflow supports some markdown styling. A better answer is more likely to be accepted!

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that worked for me.

Change this configuration:

File -> Preferences -> Settings, search for `terminal.explorerKind`, edit to `external`

or just edit the json file

```
"terminal.explorerKind": "external"
```

When VSCode prompted me telling me that using integrated was better, I followed its advice and switched. But a couple of days ago it started being very weird, in that it left a space between the actual prompt and whatever I was writing, like this:
[image: Weird vscode integrated prompt bug]
Sometimes the spacing left was of more than a dozen lines. It got instantaneously fixed once I switched back to external.

PS: This was also the case with Microsoft's Powershell terminal. I don't know if other terminals have the same issue under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, quitting VS Code with (CMD + Z) and restarting it resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

All that was needed for me was to close all VS Code instances!

Comment: Easiest solution works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occurred for me and I browsed through the VS Code issues on GitHub.
Here is the solution I found: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53782#issuecomment-414919965

Change `terminal.integrated.rendererType` back to `canvas` in VS Code settings and issue does not reappear.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to uninstall the user mode and instead install system mode. This is what Jenuel Ganawed stated and I don't know why that post is downvoted. It solves the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. I upgraded to the latest version of VSCode 1.42.1, but that didn't resolve it. It seems that the issue has to do with Powershell 2.0, so I removed it:

Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on or off->Windows PowerShell 2.0 (disable it).

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux try to kill the integrated terminal (right click and "Kill Terminal") and reopen it again ("ctrl-`").

Comment: Rebooting my computer helped as well. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you exit out of the existing terminal window. It will try to recover it and even though you may have closed out of VS Code you want to close the terminal window as well

Answer (score 0):

on my case this solved the issue
[image: File -> Preferences -> Setting -> Features -> Terminal]

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason this happens the GPU doesnt properly render the terminal the fix is to stop VS-code from using the gpu. (WARNING: If your code needs GPU dont use this Fix).

FIX:
https://gist.github.com/andriyudatama/fe5d00deb36feeea30ef35a5ea0f7eff