# Integrated terminal stops showing text in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

After a while integrated terminal stops showing text. Does anybody know the issue and walkaround?

[Integrated terminal screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFJHR.png)

[Integrated terminal screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zogr.png)

Visual Studio Code Details:

```
Version: 1.45.1
Commit: 5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
Date: 2020-05-14T08:27:22.494Z
Electron: 7.2.4
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-33-generic
```

UPDATE:
Found ref issue on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69665

Currently the only way to fix it is to zoom in\zoom out.

Comment: Is this similar to what your problem is ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092486/visual-studio-code-terminal-blank-screen

Comment: No, seems different. My bug occurs in "Python Debug Console".

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I expect to be able to see the terminals' output.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue using Remote Desktop connection to a Mac.

I had to click on the settings cog in the bottom left of the application

[image: cog icon in visual studio code]

Search for Gpu Acceleration and turn the setting off
[image: gpu acceleration setting]

Answer (score 1):

This trick seems to work:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> "Configure Runtime Arguments",

and there delete the following entry:

```
"disable-color-correct-rendering": true
```

Answer (score 0):

File -> Preferences -> Settings, open settings.json

add the following code:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
```

then restart vscode.

if not work, try this:

File -> Preferences -> Setting -> Features -> Terminal -> Inherit Env

Comment: nah, still same thing: all background becomes black and text disappears in a while. https://i.imgur.com/M6gJy5P.png

Comment: there's a similar question which has been solved, look at this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092486/visual-studio-code-terminal-blank-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not my case. I think I found issue on github tracker, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69665
Currently the only fix to get rid of problem is to zoom in\zoom out.