# text disappearing in vs code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

the text data disappearing in vs code terminal when i resize the terminal. when terminal 100% strech ( maximized ) and as i reduce the size of terminal by dragging top border of terminal as the text data start disappearing and when i maximus terminal again the whole text data is gone,
this problem occurs after i upgrades my system to windows 11. i also update powerShell to latest version

i searched on net but can't find solution please help me

Comment: This seems to be solved, when I read this on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83324

Comment: i tried the setting that they suggest and use command ctrl ++ , ctrl c+- but its not working still facing the issue

Comment: Can you try this setting (`gpu acceleration`) too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236667/724039