# vscode terminal is empty / doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: Screen Shot]

Version: 1.46.1

Commit: cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d

Date: 2020-06-17T21:13:08.304Z

Electron: 7.3.1

Chrome: 78.0.3904.130

Node.js: 12.8.1

V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0

OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-106-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually tried using the terminal? Your question provides very little information and makes it difficult for anyone to troubleshoot.

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092486/visual-studio-code-terminal-blank-screen/58647330#58647330) solution?

File -> Preferences -> Setting -> Features -> Terminal -> Inherit Env

Comment: Thanks. I am new to vscode. Checking the inhert evn checkbox made the prompt appear!

Comment: Happy to help, you should mark the answer as the solution.

Comment: Had to wait 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with ConPTY, vscode's backend for it's integrated terminal.

Try disabling it in your settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty": false
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have any terminal emulator like terminator and you are trying to open a project with it, vscode will show you an empty terminal because he don't know which terminal to use (sh, dash,rbash or bash).

to fix the issue, with your main terminal cd to the desired directory and run:

```
code .
```