# Vscode terminal for remote ssh connection not opening

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I tried connecting to a centos server using vscode remote ssh. Connection has been established but somehow the terminal is blank and it seems to not working since I can't run python files, the output is not coming.

[Blank vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w22Dh.png)

[While trying to run python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS2xQ.png)

PLease help me resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: What version of VS Code are you on?

Comment: Did you follow: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial ?

E.g. I read in the post you should see SSH: 'IP ADDRESS' in bottom left corner. Is that present and correct?

Comment: "Opening a terminal on a remote host#"

Opening a terminal on the remote host from VS Code is simple. Once connected, any terminal window you open in VS Code (Terminal > New Terminal) will automatically run on the remote host rather than locally.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Comment: What is your default remote shell?

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl The version of VS Code is 1.70.1

Comment: @Swedo The IP address is appearing at the left bottom and is correct.

Comment: @chakatz While working locally on windows the default is command prompt

Comment: My default remote shell is set to zsh. LIke you, I was also not able to open the default integrated terminal remotely on an Ubuntu server over ssh with the zsh shell but if I chose bash or tmux it worked. Eventually I restarted the remote server and zsh is working now too. It's not a fix, but it worked.

Comment: @Swedo I have followed all the steps according to the post you shared. Everything goes well but when I open terminal window it comes blank.

Comment: @DigvijayNikam Are you using Ubuntu by any chance? I found this fix for Ubuntu:
`File -> Preferences -> Setting -> Features -> Terminal -> Inherit Env`
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092486/visual-studio-code-terminal-blank-screen

Comment: @Swedo I am using windows