# My terminal in VS Code is not working and shows History restored *** or/and just blank, how to make my terminal work again?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, terminal, git-commit

The problem occured while trying to commit my code in GitHub as I forgot to pass the message -m, The code/page got committed but after that my Code terminal never worked again.

I tried to solve the terminal by different commands in cmd and powershell as well tried to change the vs code settings, also uninstalled and re-installed the app.I was expecting trminal to be reset to default or at least diplay something, still no any changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code - Terminal Blank Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092486/visual-studio-code-terminal-blank-screen)

Comment: Related: [VS Code 1.69 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_process-reconnection-and-revive-improvements) "History restored" is a message created by VS Code's terminal persistence feature.