# i am unable to type anything in my vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvXhx.png)  when i open my vs code terminal i am not able to type anything in my terminal and it even not showing any path and giving only

- History restored
- History restored   this message

i tried reinstallation but didn't help

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74673421/11107541

Comment: I suggest that you raise an issue ticket using the `Help > Report Issue` feature of VS Code. If you do, please ping me with a link to your issue ticket.