# vs code terminal doesn't showing any solution of codes or any text , it remains completely blank. How can I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJvqQ.png)

The terminal doesn't showing any output.
It remains blank.

I re-installed vscode, restarted pc , tried all possible setting changes I found on stackoverflow.
After closing and openning again and again, it behaves in a same way.

Comment: can you describe when this issue occur or after doing what this happens if any

Comment: why do you think that just typing some C code in a `.c` file gives you anything in a terminal

Comment: It occured on 26/06/23.

Comment: It used to show output in the terminal even of a simpliest 'HELLO WORLD" code .

Comment: You will need to create a simple example that reproduces the problem. We can't see all your code and don't know what steps you are taking to build and run it.

Comment: possibly a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092486/visual-studio-code-terminal-blank-screen