# How to remove the black area covering the Visual Studio Code Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I am using Visual Studio Code, version 1.8.0 and when I try to open a new terminal, I am seeing this black area covering part of it:

[image: screenshot of VS Code terminal with black area]

Seems like I can run commands from the terminal and get errors as well, for example after running `npm install` command :

[image: screenshot of VS Code terminal after running npm commands]

As you can see in the above picture, the mouse cursor is moving down a bit as I would expect from running some command (due to the output of the command), but the black area covers any visible text.

### Things I have done so far:

- Checked the solutions for similar (but not the same) question, [Visual Studio Code - Terminal Blank Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092486/visual-studio-code-terminal-blank-screen) but non of them worked for me
- Reload vscode
- check for updates (currently there are no updates available)
- Tried to open the new cmd / bash / PowerShell / git bash / command prompt terminals but the problem remains with every one of them.
- Run the same command from an external terminal (not the one integrated into vscode), the external terminal worked well.

How do I remove this black area?

Comment: It looks like the terminal might have exited because the application failed - what happens if you run a command that runs for longer or exit's with exit code 0 instead?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen seems like commands like git status are working fine (I could even copy the text under the black screen to validate it)

Comment: Its a bug (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187198) The temporary fix is to set `"terminal.integrated.enableImages": false`  in your settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating vsc to `Version: 1.80.1` the problem seems to solved.

In this new vsc version I don't see the problem anymore.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.80.1 and the problem stopped but, when I closed VS Code and reopened it, the problem came back.

Comment: please close as a dup instead of answering.

Answer (score 4):

The issue can be temporarily fixed by putting the following in your settings.json file:

"terminal.integrated.enableImages": false

Comment: please flag as a dup instead of answering.