# Why is my VS Code terminal showing a blank screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I've tried the following:

The usual Windows shut down / restart
Re-installing VS Code
Changing the default Command Line Shell from CMD to Powershell and back again
Adding a new Command Line Shell
Is there anything else I can try? Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: have you tried everything in all the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/54092486/11107541 ?